# Spring Cloud Data Flow Grafana (Prometheus) not showing stream data

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

Installed Spring Cloud Dataflow on Kubernetes (running on DockerDesktop).

Configured Grafana and Prometheus as the per the install guide https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/kubectl/

Created and deployed a simple Stream with time (source) and log (sink) from starter apps .

On selecting Stream dashboard icon in UI, navigates to grafana dashboard but DON'T see the stream and related metrics.

Am I missing any configuration here?

[image: PODs]
[image: Services]
Don't see any action in Prometheus proxy log since it started
[image: Prometheus proxy log]
**scdf-server config map**

```html
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: scdf-server
  namespace: default
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/scdf-server
  uid: ce23d5a3-1cb9-4580-ba1a-bf51b09850dc
  resourceVersion: '53607'
  creationTimestamp: '2020-04-29T01:28:36Z'
  labels:
    app: scdf-server
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    spring:
      cloud:
        dataflow:
          applicationProperties:
            stream:
              management:
                metrics:
                  export:
                    prometheus:
                      enabled: true
                      rsocket:
                        enabled: true
                        host: prometheus-proxy
                        port: 7001
            task:
              management:
                metrics:
                  export:
                    prometheus:
                      enabled: true
                      rsocket:
                        enabled: true
                        host: prometheus-proxy
                        port: 7001
          grafana-info:
            url: 'http://localhost:3000'
          task:
            platform:
              kubernetes:
                accounts:
                  default:
                    limits:
                      memory: 1024Mi
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST}:${MYSQL_SERVICE_PORT}/mysql
        username: root
        password: ${mysql-root-password}
        driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
        testOnBorrow: true
        validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
```

[image: Prometheus Datasource Test]

[image: Deployed Stream]
[image: The Stream doesn't show-up in grafana]

[image: Grafana Home]

**[Following fixed the Issue]**

I updated the stream definition set below in Applications.Properties it started working fine.

management.metrics.export.prometheus.rsocket.host=prometheus-proxy

[image: Revised Stream Property]
[image: Grafana - now working as expected]

Comment: Looking at the pod-list (and no errors), it looks like everything is up and running correctly. Especially, if you didn't have to change anything in the stock deployment YAMLs, it should all come together seamlessly. Perhaps you can update the post with the SCDF version in use, and we can review the set up on our side, too.

Comment: Thank you, Sabby. I found the issue, it started working after I updated the stream definition and in the Applications.Properties set
management.metrics.export.prometheus.rsocket.host=prometheus-proxy

Comment: Name: spring-cloud-dataflow-server
Version: 2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 2):

This metrics collection flow diagram from https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/monitoring-samples helped to spot the issue quick. Thanks

[image: Metrics collection flow]

Comment: for future readers who come across this question, can you explain what exactly the issue was and what its solution was, which you found in that link you posted?